# find difference of daily comparison using javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
[{date:'2017-8-1',count: 100},
{date:'2017-8-2',count: 200},
{date:'2017-8-3',count: 101},
{date:'2017-8-4',count: 123},
{date:'2017-8-5',count: 14},
{date:'2017-8-6',count: 12},
{date:'2017-8-7',count: 2},
{date:'2017-8-8',count: 3}] //today
```

I have 8 array item, I want to find the difference of each day. But I don't know how to calculate the difference of previous day. For example the difference between 2017-8-8 compare to 2017-8-7 is 1, how do I need to do the loop?

Comment: Do you want the calculate the number of days between two dates ?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia count btw current and previous day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach` to calculate the difference between two adjacent count values in the array like this:

```js
var data = [{date:'2017-8-1',count: 100},
{date:'2017-8-2',count: 200},
{date:'2017-8-3',count: 101},
{date:'2017-8-4',count: 123},
{date:'2017-8-5',count: 14},
{date:'2017-8-6',count: 12},
{date:'2017-8-7',count: 2},
{date:'2017-8-8',count: 3}];

var result = [];
data.forEach(function(obj, idx) {
  if(!idx) return;
  result.push(data[idx].count - data[idx-1].count);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can use map in this case?

Comment: @CeciliaChan `map` will return the same number of elements as of original array. Whereas the adjacent differences will be one less than array length. So `map` is not a good choice here, however you can use `Array#reduce`

Comment: reduce will not have the problem that map has?

Comment: @CeciliaChan `Array#reduce` is used where you need to reduce the array to a single value (integer, array, object etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `new Date("2017-8-8").getDate()`

i hope this will help you :)

```js
var input = [{date:'2017-8-1',count: 100},
{date:'2017-8-2',count: 200},
{date:'2017-8-3',count: 101},
{date:'2017-8-4',count: 123},
{date:'2017-8-5',count: 14},
{date:'2017-8-6',count: 12},
{date:'2017-8-7',count: 2},
{date:'2017-8-8',count: 3}];
for(var i = input.length-1; i>0; i--){
   var dateDiff = new Date(input[i].date).getDate() - new Date(input[i-
   1].date).getDate();
   //pushing the diff in input array
   input[i].diffFromPrevEntry = dateDiff;
}
console.log(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that calculates the differences.

```js
var dataArray = [
{date:'2017-8-1',count: 100},
{date:'2017-8-2',count: 200},
{date:'2017-8-3',count: 101},
{date:'2017-8-4',count: 123},
{date:'2017-8-5',count: 14},
{date:'2017-8-6',count: 12},
{date:'2017-8-7',count: 2},
{date:'2017-8-8',count: 3}
];

function calculateDifferences(data) {
  var result = [];
  
  // Start at index 1 instead of 0 so we immediately have a previous item.
  for (var index=1; index<data.length; index++) {
  // Get the item at the current and previous index.
      var previousItem = data[index - 1],
          currentItem = data[index];
    // Push an object into the result array with the start and 
    // end date, as well as the difference between the count of the two days.
    result.push({
      startDate: previousItem.date,
      endDate: currentItem.date,
      difference: currentItem.count - previousItem.count
    });    
  }
  
  // Return the array with the result.
  return result;
}

// Log the result of the method.
console.log(calculateDifferences(dataArray));
```